Building a string with array values
I have the following code which splits a string and gets the four values separated by a delimiter.
I want to build a result string like this:
/result = "<div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"heading\">"+arr[0]+"</div> <div class=\"heading\">"+arr[1]+"</div></div><div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"resultname\">"+arr[2]+"</div> <div class=\"resultname\">"+arr[3]+"</div></div>";
And I don't want to hardcode the array like arr[0], arr[1], etc. I was wondering if there's a better way to handle this. The for loop I've defined in the later portion of below code is definitely not the correct way to handle this.
public class StringExtraction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "|555|777|AB|CD";
        String[] arr = str.substring(1).split("\\|");

        String result = "";
        //result = "<div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"heading\">"+arr[0]+"</div> <div class=\"heading\">"+arr[1]+"</div></div><div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"resultname\">"+arr[2]+"</div> <div class=\"resultname\">"+arr[3]+"</div></div>";

        System.out.println("Array length is :-> " + arr.length);
        for (String s1 : arr) {
            System.out.println("Value " + s1 + " and its length is " + s1.length());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            result = "<div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"heading\">" + arr[i] + "</div> <div class=\"heading\">" + arr[i] + "</div></div><div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"resultname\">" + arr[i] + "</div> <div class=\"resultname\">" + arr[i] + "</div></div>";
        }

        System.out.println("Print Result below:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}


You could put the possible HTML strings into an array as well, add %s to each HTML string in place of their value, and then format() each HTML string to replace the format specifier with the actual value.
Your code could look something like this:
public class StringExtraction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strValues = "|555|777|AB|CD";
        String[] vetValues = strValues.substring(1).split("\\|");
        String[] vetHTML = new String[]{
                "<div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"heading\">%s",
                "</div> <div class=\"heading\">%s",
                "</div></div><div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"resultname\">%s",
                "</div> <div class=\"resultname\">%s</div></div>"
        };
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vetValues.length; i++) {
            vetHTML[i] = String.format(vetHTML[i], vetValues[i]);
        }

        String result;
        //result = "<div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"heading\">"+vetValues[0]+"</div> <div class=\"heading\">"+vetValues[1]+"</div></div><div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"resultname\">"+vetValues[2]+"</div> <div class=\"resultname\">"+vetValues[3]+"</div></div>";
        result = String.join("", vetHTML);

        System.out.println("Print Result below:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

Here is also a demo at OneCompiler.

I couldn't help but wonder if dani-vta's excellent response could be made reusable, here I leave two options (depending on the type of input), which allow you to easily implement the solution to other use cases:
If we receive the "html" as a string:
String html = "<div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"heading\"> </div> <div class=\"heading\"> </div></div><div class=\"parent\"> <div class=\"resultname\"> </div> <div class=\"resultname\"> </div></div>";
        
  // create an array with insert positions
int positions[] = { 1, 3, 7, 9 };

String str = "|555|777|AB|CD";

String insertInHtml( String html, String inputs, int positions[] ) {

    String[] arr = inputs.substring( 1 ).split( "\\|" );
    int positionX = -1, positionX2 = -1;
    String newHtml = "";
    int valueItem = 0;
    String value = "";

    for( int i = 0; true; i ++ ) {
        positionX = html.indexOf( "<", positionX + 1 );
        if( positionX == -1 )
            break;
        positionX2 = html.indexOf( ">", positionX2 + 1 );
        if( valueItem < arr.length && i == positions[ valueItem ] )
            value = arr[ valueItem ++ ];
        newHtml += html.substring( positionX, positionX2 + 1 ) + value + "\n";
        value = "";
    }
    return newHtml;
}

if we receive the "html" as an array:
String html[] = {
    "<div class=\"parent\">",
    "<div class=\"heading\">",
    "</div> ",
    "<div class=\"heading\">",
    " </div>",
    "</div>",
    "<div class=\"parent\">",
    "<div class=\"resultname\">",
    "</div>",
    "<div class=\"resultname\">",
    "</div>",
    "</div>"
};

String[] insertInHtml( String html[], String input, int positions[] ) {

    String[] arr = str.substring( 1 ).split( "\\|" );
    String newHtml = "";
    int valueItem = 0;

    for( int i = 0; true; i ++ ) {
        if( valueItem == arr.length ) break;
        if(  i == positions[ valueItem ] )
           html[ i ] += html[ i ] + arr[ valueItem++ ];
    }
    return html;
}


Alternative using String::formatted and Text Blocks, available since Java 15:
public class StringExtraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "|555|777|AB|CD";
        String[] arr = str.substring(1).split("\\|");

        String result = """
            <div class="parent"> <div class="heading">%s</div> \
            <div class="heading">%s</div></div>\
            <div class="parent"> <div class="resultname">%s</div> \
            <div class="resultname">%s</div></div>\
            """.formatted((Object[])arr);

        System.out.println("Print Result below:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

The backslash \ at line end is needed to avoid line breaks included into the String. Single double-quotes " must not be escaped in Text Blocks.

Loops can be used if a different number of rows or columns are allowed:
public class StringExtraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "|555|777|AB|CD";
        String[] arr = str.substring(1).split("\\|");

        var columns = 2;
        var i = 0;
        
        // header
        var result = "<div class=\"parent\"> ";
        for (var col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            result += "<div class=\"%s\">%s</div> ".formatted("heading", arr[i++]);
        }
        result += "</div>\n"; // added newline for readability

        // row(s)
        while (i < arr.length) {
            result += "<div class=\"parent\"> ";
            for (var col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
                result += "<div class=\"%s\">%s</div>".formatted("resultname", arr[i++]);
            }
            result += "</div>\n"; // added newline for readability
        }
 
        System.out.println("Print Result below:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

This will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the number of data columns is not divisible by columns!

If there are only four values involved, I don't see why it is a problem to work with hardcoded indices. Creating a new array for the remaining html tags and attributes, as in the accepted answer, doesn't make it much better, let alone more readable. But if you insist, then I would use a stingbuilder
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input     = "|555|777|AB|CD";
    String[] values  = input.substring(1).split("\\|");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sb.append("<div class=\"parent\">");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        sb.append(i < 2 ? "  <div class=\"heading\">" : "  <div class=\"resultname\">");
        sb.append(values[i]).append("</div>");
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            sb.append("</div>");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}

output below. Remove System.lineSeparator() and spaces if you want all in one line
<div class="parent">
  <div class="heading">555</div>
  <div class="heading">777</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="resultname">AB</div>
  <div class="resultname">CD</div>
</div>

